# How to sys.stderr.write into a json file in Python?

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob

I am running a MapReduce job with [mrjob](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob) library and I want to record the execution time to a `json` file.

I record the time with this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42517457/9500955):

```py
from datetime import datetime
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = datetime.now()
    MRJobClass.run()
    end_time = datetime.now()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    sys.stderr.write(elapsed_time)
```

I have to print the time to `stderr` because it only works with this method.

I cannot use this code to write to `json` file because my code will run in distributed mode:

```py
data = {}
data["step1"] = elapsed_time
with open('time.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

How can I write the elapsed time to the JSON file in local folder with `sys.stderr.write()`?

Answer (score 1):

`json.dump` writes to a file-like object--meaning it has a `.write(str)` method. `sys.stderr` is a file-like object:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import time
import json

start_time = datetime.now()
time.sleep(1)
elapsed_time = datetime.now() - start_time
data = {"step1":str(elapsed_time)}
json.dump(data,sys.stderr)
```

Output:

```
{"step1": "0:00:01.004999"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does write the time into stderr in JSON format. How can I save it to local from this?

Comment: @huy I'm not sure what you mean.  "save to local" is what you were doing before...open a file and write to it.

Comment: My program will get the input file from HDFS and save the output to HDFS. So it does not use any local file. I want to save the time into a `json` file in the local directory so that other jobs can use this file and continue to add the time.

Comment: @huy Full disclosure I know nothing about hadoop/mrjob so you'll have to be more specific.  But a JSON file is not an appendable unless you use a format like [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/), where each line of the file is a complete JSON object.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your answer, I think I can find some idea about this.

Comment: The computer I use to execute this code is called Node Master. In Hadoop distributed mode, when I run a MapReduce code, it will bring this code to many computers and execute the program there so I cannot open and write the JSON file in my Node Master.

Comment: So using `sys.stderr.write` or your method, I can watch it from the terminal on Node Master.

Comment: Now I just want to write that into a file on Node Master.